# How can showing data which get from Json in separate boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#go").click(function () {
            setInterval(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetMyBooks",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var htm = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                            htm.push("" + response.d[i].BOOK_NAME + "" + response.d[i].BOOK_DESC + "");
                        };
                        $("#pejiGrid").html(htm.join(',,,,,,'));
                    },

            }, 5000);
        }); 
      });
```

it shows some information in Div tag by id :'pejiGrid', in this shap :

> MyBookName1MyBookDescription1,,,,,,MyBookName2MyBookDescription2

it is not a good shape, i want to show this data in seperate box with a Close button (i dont want an alert), i want to put "MyBookName1MyBookDescription1" in one box and "MyBookName2MyBookDescription2" in another box and about another information too. How can i do it?

EDIT: I have following HTML Tags :

```
<div id="go">Click</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="pejiGrid"></div>
```

Comment: can you post any relevant html code as well?

Comment: I added relevant html code

Answer (score 0):

use `append` function.

https://api.jquery.com/append

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#go").click(function () {
        setInterval(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetMyBooks",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                         $("#pejiGrid")
                        .append("<div class='box'>"+response.d[i].BOOK_NAME + response.d[i].BOOK_DESC + "<a href='#' class='close'>Close</a></div>"); 
                    };
                },

        }, 5000);
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: you would have to style the `div.box` element accordingly ofcourse

Comment: what about the close button? I want appear a close button on these boxes

Comment: I do your solution but it's close button is not work!!

Comment: you need to add a click handler for that button. that is beyond the scope of your question. we can't do everything for you

Comment: I added this code for close button but it's not work, may you help me?  $('.close').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.box').fadeOut(1000);
     } );

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47593/discussion-between-pejman-and-anurupr)